# Is it ok to use "meanwhile" at the end of a sentence to mean "at the same time"?

Tags: word-usage

For example:

He said that many people were sick at the same time.

He said that many people were sick meanwhile. (?)

Answer (score 2):

No.

"Meanwhile" has the sense of "at the same time *as something else*" not "at the same time as each other".

The first sentence is understood to mean that the people were sick at the same time as each other.  The second sentence is not understandable as no "something else" is mentioned.

The dictionary example is

> "Steam for a further five minutes. Meanwhile, make a white sauce"

The "something else" is "steam for five minutes" which you do at the same time as making a white sauce.  Normally "meanwhile" comes at the start, not the end.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!